# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings not working

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

### Below is my app.config file

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="input_file" value="D:\bioen\Web\NewUser\dotnet\PasswordGenerator\AutoPassword\AutoPassword\Passwords.txt"/>
    <add key="location" value="sequals"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

---

when I attempt to read this values in a program like what is shown below,
both strings are null. Why is this?

---

```
string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["input_file"];
string location = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["location"];
```

Comment: most likely the app is reading a different config file. Use procmon to see what its doing

Comment: absolutely correct @pm100,

Comment: just in case - procmon = https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor

Comment: Make sure that you added the app.config file at the right place and you might be having multiple projects, the app.config file should go into the startup project i.e. the one with the presentation layer or the executable one such as a console application, WPF application or an ASP.NET application

Comment: Firs check whether you have .config in your application directory. If so, check whether you have correct entries that you are looking for.

Comment: See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623600/1467396 if you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you are missing a reference to the System.Configuration.dll.

Right click on project, add reference to System.Configuration dll and hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

- App.Config is for reading design time config, such as Entity Framework reads from this.
- Strongly typed settings needed adding in Settings tab of a project's properties page. You can choose their scope, such as Application or User. These will be added to Settings.Designer file of the project.

Application settings are accessed by My.Settings.<settingsname> (in VB.NET) or Properties.Settings.Default.<settingsname> (in C#).